# In Openshift, how to prestart a script before the main server.js start?

Tags: openshift

I want to start a crawler.js to fetch some pages from the Internet before the server.js starts. I have tried to change the package.json to ' "scripts":prestart:crawler.js '. But it seems it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

prestart script described in `package.json` works only if you start the node app via `npm start`command. More information about this: [1](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts),[2](http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/08/11/what-does-npm-start-do-in-nodejs/)

This is the perfect way if you use your local machine but OpenShift works in a different way. It uses [node-supervisor](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor) to run your node app. This supervisor runs `node server.js` from your $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR by default to start your node app. You can't change this behaviour.

Openshift allows you to define Action Hooks for this type of job. You have to write scripts (in shell or python or ruby etc.) and place them in `<repository>/.openshift/action_hooks`.  These scripts are executed by OpenShift at different times like Cartridge start, stop, restart or during default build lifecycle. Read the [documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/action-hooks.html) carefully to understand how they work and use them in your application.

There is also an example action hook that checks if there is a data in a MongoDB database and if not, it imports data from the git repository for the application.

Comment: Note that action hooks are only relevant to OpenShift 2. If they are using OpenShift 3 then action hooks are not provided by the default node S2I builder.